# Manifest activity no launched

Tags: android, android-manifest

When I put Manifest file and the controller which has a function setting a pendingIntent to show the dialog defined in the manifest file in the same directory, the dialog can be triggered successfully. But after I separated them into different directory, the dialog can no longer be trigger. I've updated the path for the dialog in the manifest file, but I don't know why the new folder structure is no longer working. Should the manifest file be in the same directory with the dialog activity class file?

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android=""
package=""
>

<application>
  <activity
      android:name="path to dialog"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true"
      android:exported="false"
      android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:permission=""
      android:taskAffinity=""
      android:theme=""
      />
</application>
</manifest>
```

```
Here is the original folder structure, which is working:

--showdialog
    --BUCK 
    --AndroidManifest.xml
    --Dialog.class
    --Controller.class


Here is the new folder structure, no longer working:
--showdialog
    --AndroidManifest.xml
    --controller
      --BUCK
      --Controller.class
    --dialog
      --BUCK
      --Dialog.class
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is the question?

Comment: I've updated the path for the dialog in the manifest file after changing the folder structure, but I don't know why the new folder structure is no longer working (dialog cannot be triggered after change).

Comment: If you are clicking on the path mentioned in the AndroidManifest is it taking you to the actual file?

Comment: Are you actually putting compiled .class files in your folders?  How are you launching this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android=""
package="com.example.app"
>

<application>
  <activity
      android:name=".MainDialog"
      android:excludeFromRecents="true"
      android:exported="false"
      android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:permission=""
      android:taskAffinity=""
      android:theme=""
      />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Make sure that the `MainDialog` follows java class path of `com.example.app`.

ie;

The package name of MainDialog should look something like,

```
package com.example.app;

public class MainDialog {

}
```

Whatever you specify within `android:name` goes after the specified package name ("com.example.app").

Let us know how it goes.